# Dynamically embed HTML5 video for iPad

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, video, embed

What is the correct way to embed HTML5 video dynamically so it works on the iPad? (with plain Javascript)

This isn't working:

```
<div id="placeholder"><script type="text/javascript" src="embedvideo.js"></script></div>
```

Here's the code for embedvideo.js:

```
var div = document.getElementById('placeholder');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<video width="800" height="450" poster="image.jpg" controls><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere are you calling the function. So you need to include the script in the head and call the function to insert it.

Comment: I see, the only thing I can think of then is the codec for your video. is there an example I can see?